# Художник - от слова "худо"

Tags: словообразование, этимология

О плохом художнике говорят «художник от слова "худо"». Но так ли это на самом деле? Откуда в русском языке взялось это слово?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, конечно. Художник, художество - от архаичного общеславянского "худога" - ловкость, искусность. А это слово в свою очередь родственно германскому hand - рука.
"Худо" родственно "худой" - плохой. Это тоже общеславянский корень, но совершенно другого происхождения.
Правда, согласно Фасмеру, в диалектах возможно "художество" в значении что-то плохое, никчемное. Но это окказиональное образование по аналогии с "убожество".

Answer (score -1):

> А как имена Бога по смыслу связаны с
> художником?

Может быть, как Создатель, Творец
Творец - творчество

Answer (score -1):

Изображение Бога и есть художество, синоним иконописи.

Answer (score -2):

А иду я на Русь, кѣтъмышьтыр имень, урусь тутътым. Мѣсяць мартъ прошел, и яз заговѣлъ з бесермены в недѣлю, да говѣл есми мѣсяць, мяса есми не ѣлъ и ничего скоромнаго, никакие ѣствы бесерменские, а ѣлъ есми по двожды на день хлѣбъ да воду, авратыйля ятмадым. Да молился есми Христу Вседрьжителю, кто сотворил небо и землю, а иного есми не призывал никоторого именемъ, Богь олло, Богъ керим, Богъ рагимъ, Богь **худо**, Богъ акьберь, Богъ царь славы, олло варенно, олло рагимельно сеньсень олло ты.
А иду я на Русь с думой: погибла вера моя, постился я бесерменским постом. Месяц март прошел, начал я пост с бесерменами в воскресенье, постился месяц, ни мяса не ел, ничего скоромного, никакой еды бесерменской не принимал, а ел хлеб да воду два раза на дню, с женщиной не ложился я. И молился я Христу Вседержителю, кто сотворил небо и землю, а иного Бога именем не призывал. Господи Боже, Бог милостивый, Бог милосердный, Бог **Господь**, Бог великий, Бог царь славы, Бог зиждитель, Бог всемилостивейший, — это все ты, о Господи.

Худо - God - Gott - Худа (Иран) - Кудай (Казах) - Всё это ИМЕНА ЕДИНОГО БОГА. 
Афанасий Никитин в 1475 году так обращался к Христу Богу. Какая уж тут "архаика"? Обычный достаточно поздний "перевёртыш" типа "чё зенки-то вылупил?" - SENKEN, по нем. ОЧИ(поэт) Да и MUNDSTUECK вставляется в рот, а не в другое место (и т.д.)

Comment: >Худо - God - Gott - Худа (Иран) - Кудай (Казах) - Всё это ИМЕНА ЕДИНОГО БОГА.

А как имена Бога по смыслу связаны с художником?

Comment: А , вот , интересно по украiнской мове слово ХУДОБА ,  по-русски = ДОМАШНИЙ СКОТ  , как Вы истолкуете с точки зрения связи с ЕДИНЫМ БОГОМ ? С учётом того , что на Украiни скотина вовсе НЕ х у д а я  , а вполне-таки упитанная ?! Ха-ха-ха !

Answer (score -2):

Художник, на примере Пиранези - худо (плохое, беда) жник (жнец, жатва). Собирающий факты беды. Изображения Пиранези - хронология реальных объектов после какого то события. И с этой точки зрения все логично вяжется. Особенно учитывая тот факт что Пиранези это древнейшие гравюры, а значит и слово могло пойти с тех самых пор

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Пиранези работал в древнейшем XVIII в. На его листах — руины и городские пейзажи, по большей части — архитектурные фантазии.